# Close form immediately in WinForms application

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

When calling `Close()` method, the form does not close immediately. It has to wait for other code (e.g: all running methods) to be completed. *Note: this behavior doesn't occur on the main form*.

**What I want to achieve:**

```
Private Sub Dummy()
    If foo() Then Close()
    If bar() Then Close()

    'Other code that shouldn't be reached
    'if 'foo()' or 'bar()' returned true.
End Sub
```

- I do **NOT** want to call `foo()` and `bar()`, check for both values, and then call `Close()`.
- I know that I can do something like:

  ```
  If foo() Then
      Close()
      Exit Sub ' Or (Return)
  End If
  ```

But I'm looking for something simpler and -preferably- will close the form immediately without returning to the caller method *if there's any*.

- Is there any way to achieve this?
- Is it not the right approach?

Comment: If we have method `A()` that calls method `B()`, and want to call `Close()` from method `B()`. In this case code in method `A()` will still be executed. I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

> will close the form immediately **without returning to the caller method if there's any.**

There's **ALWAYS** a caller method, even if that method is just the Windows event loop/message pump. If there's no caller method, then the program quits. That's how stack-based programming environments that define pretty much all modern computer systems work: methods are pushed onto the call stack when called, popped when they end, and when there's nothing left on the stack the program is done.

Even within your code for your program or form, what you're asking for is the same as bypassing the caller's entry on the stack, which is equivalent (or worse) to using GOTO, as it breaks the foundational rules of structured programming.

If you really want the program to quit, you can try `Environment.Exit()`. Otherwise, `Exit Sub` or `Return` is your best option.

Comment: +1 Thanks for clarifying this out. I do not want to exit the program. I just want to close the current form and return to the previous one. (By `caller method` I mean any caller method in the current form).

Comment: I see. So there's no way to drop all current form's methods from the stack, and close the form immediately? (I mean something like `Application.Exit()` but not extended to the whole application)

Answer (score 1):

As the other's have stated, there is not a easier pattern than that which you have posted.

> If we have method A() that calls method B(), and want to call Close() from method B(). In this case code in method A() will still be executed.

If you want to exit out of MethodA if the form has been closed in MethodB, you can check the form's `IsDisposed` property.  It will be `True` after calling `Form.Close`.  Alternatively, you could check the `Form.Visble` property in MethodA; it will be `False` if the form has been closed.

Something like this:

```
Sub MethodA()
    MethodB()
    If Me.IsDisposed Then Exit Sub
    ' some more code to run if Form is not closed
End Sub

Sub MethodB()
    If foo() Then
        Me.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If bar() Then
        Me.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Close()` and `Exit Sub` approach is as simple as you could hope for, really :)

Close() won't terminate the current procedure in VB.Net WinForms, by design.  So I think the `Exit Sub` approach you mentioned is the cleanest way.  `Close()`'s behavior is a little odd, but it allows for scenarios where cleanup code can continue to run, but with the knowledge the form will close when the subroutine has finished.

Comment: Well, this approach might be simple, but if there are some caller methods, it won't work for them as well.

Comment: Caller methods will finish too, all the way up the stack tree.

Comment: Thanks again, but nope. `Exit Sub` or `Return` will exit only the current procedure, and continue running the caller ones. You can try it yourself.

Comment: The other answer seems to have understood that you are trying to do something impossible, I just thought you were looking for a simpler way of stopping the execution of the current procedure.

Comment: Oh I see. No I wanted to close the current form without executing any more code. But yes, looks like it's not possible.. I just wanted to make sure :)